# Computing exponential of a matrix without Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

is it possible to find the exponential of a matrix without the Jordan normal form (not a numerical approximation)? I've been thinking about this problem and trying to tackle it using a more general approach with the rational form but I failed to find an appropriate solution

Comment: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/19ways+.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{K})$ where $K$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ (for example). If you don't know exactly all the eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)_i$ of $A$, then you cannot calculate exactly the values of $e^A$ or $\sqrt A$ or $\log(A)$ or $\cdots$. -Note that we should define what we mean by "we know explicitly this or that number"-

In particular, if $n\geq 5$ and $A$ is random, then we cannot calculate $e^A$ -with probability $1$- because $\chi_A$ is not solvable -with probability $1$-.

The first thing to see is that the problem reduces to the case of the semi-simple matrices. Indeed, we can always calculate the Jordan Chevalley decomposition of $A$, that is, $A=D+N$, where $D\in K[A]$ is semi-simple, $N\in K[A]$ is nilpotent and $DN=ND$. Then $e^A=e^D(I+N+\cdots+\dfrac{N^{n-1}}{(n-1)!})$. It "remains" to calculate $e^D$, that is impossible; indeed, it is not difficult to see that the entries of $e^D$ are in the extension of $K$ containing the entries of $A$, the $(\lambda_i)$ and the $(e^{\lambda_i})$.

Now, if you are satisfied with an approximation of $e^A$ (in fact you have no choice), then you can do as follows; assume that $A\in M_5$ with $|a_{i,j}|\leq 1$. We work with $30$ significative digits

Let $B=2^{-10}A$, $r$ be the remainder of the division of $\sum_{i=0}^{10}x^i/i!$ by $\chi_B$. Put $s=r(B)$ and do

for i from 1 to 10 do s:=s^2:od:

The output $s$ is a good approximation of $e^A$.

EDIT. -Answer to Reinhard Meier- Absolutely, and this is what makes the interest of this algorithm.

The Jordan-Chevalley decomposition uses only operations in $K$, in fact a finite number of such operations and, moreover, the complexity of the algorithm is polynomial (in $O(n^3)$ or $O(n^4)$).

The idea is as follows: we assume that $K$ is a perfect field (every irreducible $P\in K[x]$ has only simple roots).

Let $P\in K[x]$ be irreducible; with a like-Newton method, we can construct a sequence $(Q_i)_{i\geq 1}\in K[x]$ s.t. $Q_1(x)=x,P(Q_i(x))=0 \mod P^i$ and $Q_i(x)=x \mod P$.

Let $U\in M_n(K)$; there is $P\in K[x]$ irreducible s.t. $P^m(U)=0$. Then (cf. above) $U=D+(U-D)$ where $D=Q_m(U)$. Moreover, $D\in K[U],P(D)=0,(U-D)^m=0$.

A reference in french

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.5020.pdf

Comment: Is there a way of getting the Jordan Chevalley decomposition that does not involve calculating the Jordan normal form? The OP asks specifically for methods that do not require the Jordan normal form.

Comment: Thank you very much for extending the answer with the details about the Jordan Chevalley decomposition! This is cool. I didn't know that there is a way of accomplishing the decomposition without the Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods of finding the exponential of a matrix.

One method is the diagonalization of the matrix which requires having linearly independent eigenvectors.

The other method is using the Cayley Hamilton  Theorem which does not require the eigenvector and takes advantage of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix.

If you are lucky and you can find the infinite series approach, then that is also possible for some simple matrices.

Comment: The first method uses the Jordan form, the second method is interesting but I'm not really sure if the rest of the polynomial division converges

Comment: $e^{tA}=\alpha_1(t)I+\alpha_2(t)A+...+\alpha_{n}(t)A^{n-1}$ then replace $A$ with eigenvalues and solve for $\alpha s$ then let $t=1$

Comment: what if my matrix doesn't have eigenvalues?

Comment: Every matrix has eigenvalues.

Comment: could you please elaborate on your ideas? Do you mean matrices on an algebraically closed field? Or do you mean that you can extend the field so that eigenvalues exist? and if it's the latter, why is it clear that the exponential of a matrix on the ground field and on the extended field are equal?

Comment: @wostysums More precisely, diagonlization is a special case of Jordan Canonical Form where each block is 1$\times$1.

Comment: @Acccumulation I know and I explicitly said in my question that I'm not looking for a proof using the Jordan form :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the field is $\mathbb{C}.$

You do not need the Jordan normal form, but you need the eigenvalues.

Let $H$ be the Hermite interpolation polynomial of maximum degree $n-1$ that interpolates an analytic function $f$ at the eigenvalues of $A$ with the associated algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalues. This means, if $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with algebraic multiplicity $r_i,$ then we calculate the polynomial coefficients of $H$ such that
$$
H(\lambda_i) = f(\lambda_i) \\
H'(\lambda_i) = f'(\lambda_i) \\
H''(\lambda_i) = f''(\lambda_i) \\
H^{(r_i-1)}(\lambda_i) = f^{(r_i-1)}(\lambda_i)
$$
which is always possible. This is a regular system of $n$ linear equations with $n$ unknows.

Then $f(A) = H(A).$ You can use this with $f(t) = e^t$.

Comment: The existence of the Jordan normal form is equivalent to the assumption that the Field you're working on is algebraically closed (in your case $\mathbb{C}$ )